# Migration problem. "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed". Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

Here are my tables:

**Users table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('username')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->integer('subscriber_id')->unsigned(); 
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('subscriber_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('subscribers');
    });
}
```

**Subscribers table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('subscribers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Everytime I "php artisan migrate" this message always prompts and blocks me on migrating:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create
 table `emade`.`#sql-de4_9e` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
 (SQL: alter table `users` add constraint `users_subscriber_id_foreign` foreign key (`subs
criber_id`) references `subscribers` (`id`))
```

I just confused on above lines returned:
1. **can't create table 'emade'** - 'emade' is not my table, it is my database
2. **users_subscriber_id_foreign** ??

I had burn a lot of time of this problem. I have really no idea whats happening, Sirs, please help..

Comment: @TimLewis Version 5.7.12, using MySql on xampp only. Sorry for inconvenient.

Comment: The error is that it cannot create the temporary table `#sql-de4_9e`, not your database `emade`.  I do not use Laravel's schema generation and can only assume you have the correct API usage, but does the `subscribers` table already exist when you try to create the `users` table?  The `subscribers.id` must match exactly. `users.subscriber_id` is `UNSIGNED`, but is `subscribers.id` also `UNSIGNED`?

Comment: Don't worry about `users_subscriber_id_foreign` - that is a constraint name that Laravel appears to be generating if you did not explicitly supply one. In practice you don't need to use those names much unless you are manipulating the constraints in your schema.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski thank you Sir, your first comment really helps. I create first the "subscriber" table and then the "user" table. But I just doubt Sir if I'm gonna push the project to remote(gitlab) and then pull it on the other device, should I do the same thing Sir? migrate this table first and then this?

Comment: It should be possible to name the migrations' files by modifying their timestamps so that the subscribers table migration is run first. This blog describes the process, but I cannot verify it as I do not use Laravel - 
I just know that the parent table must always be created before the child table in a FK relationship. https://blog.kongnir.com/2015/03/08/laravel-order-of-migrations-with-foreign-keys/

Comment: What are the filenames of your migration files?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski thanks sir got your idea.